# How to fetch data from json file using getJSON

Tags: jquery

I am fetching data from external JSON file. I want to fetch location from the file, but there is an output of "undefined". Can anyone help me with this?

---

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
      var output = "<ul class='search'>";
      $.each(data, function (key, value) {
           output += '<li>';
           output += '<h2>' + value.location + '</h2>';
           output += '</li>';
      });
      output += "<ul/>";
      $('#update').html(output);
   })
});
```

---

**JSON**

```
"data": [{
    "slug": "allsopp-allsopp",
    "id": 401,
    "imageToken": "d045e18526f988cceb63b08e71180fb6595d9f27",
    "name": "Allsopp & Allsopp",
    "location": "Dubai",
    "description": "Allsopp & Allsopp is a family founded property services company operating a traditional UK estate agency model in the United Arab Emirates (UAE). Our mandate is to deliver levels of customer care well above prevailing industry benchmarks, in a rapid and result oriented fashion which adheres strictly to the regulatory framework now governing the local property market. Consequently the staff we employ are expected to follow a business methodology which demands exceptional honesty, a stringent code of business conduct and total transparency to the client. The key objective at Allsopp & Allsopp is to be an all embracing property service centre that caters to all types of property related transactions in the UAE.",
    "residentialForRentCount": 521,
    "residentialForSaleCount": 1114,
    "commercialForRentCount": 1,
    "commercialForSaleCount": 0,
    "commercialTotalCount": 1,
    "totalProperties": 1636,
    "agentCount": 57,
    "licenseLabel": "RERA",
    "licenseNumber": "1815",
    "phone": "+971 4 429 4444",
    "links": {
        "self": "/en/broker/allsopp-allsopp-401",
        "logo": "https://www.propertyfinder.ae/images/pf_broker/logo/d045e18526f988cceb63b08e71180fb6595d9f27/desktop",
        "logo2x": "https://www.propertyfinder.ae/images/pf_broker/logo/d045e18526f988cceb63b08e71180fb6595d9f27/desktop2x"
    }
}
```

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="searcharea"></div>
<div id="update"></div>
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. If it's an object, there should be `{}` around the whole thing, and then the loop should be `$.each(data.data, ...)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/316/ajax/4209/all-in-one-examples#t=201610242036130058759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### #1 - Check if your JSON is valid  [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/#)

(It's not). You need to  add an extra `{` at the start of the file before `"data": [{` and add `]}` at the end

#### #2 - Debug or use console.log to know what you are reading

Print `key`and `value`, inside the `$.each` function, so you can understand what you are reading.

#### #3 - Check what is `value`, and if does exist any `value.location`

You need extra precautions for `links` property.
This property of the main object, is another Object itself, with his own properties, it is not a string or number like the others keys.